# Performance Tuning

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need input on the below queries in terms of which one is better from performance perspective.

Query#1:

```
DECLARE @Var1 NVARCHAR(15) = NULL; -- This variable can have NULL or specific value

SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Col1 = ISNULL(@Var1, Col1);
```

Query#2:

```
DECLARE @Var1 NVARCHAR(15) = NULL; -- This variable can have NULL or specific value

SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE (@Var1 IS NULL OR Col1 = @Var1);
```

Comment: Can Col1 be NULL?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that they're both equally bad. Neither one is [SARGable](https://blogs.msmvps.com/robfarley/2010/01/21/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/). Wrapping columns in functions, or applying [optional parameters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2010/04/22/conor-vs-optional-parameters/) can harm performance, prevent the efficient use of indexes, etc.

The one upside of the second query is that you can apply a [RECOMPILE hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017) to get around some performance issues:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, ... 
FROM dbo.Table1 
WHERE (@Var1 IS NULL OR Col1 = @Var1)
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

But you may introduce overhead with plan creation if the actual query is more complex and has a larger execution plan, or if it executes frequently (think hundreds or thousands of times a minute).

The typical solution is to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Var1 NVARCHAR(15) = NULL; -- This variable can have NULL or specific value
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE 1 = 1' 
IF @Var1 IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL += ' AND Col1 = @iVar1'
    END;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@iVar1 NVARCHAR(15)', @iVar1 = @Var1;
```

This is written safely to prevent [SQL injection](https://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/).